# Weird behavior of ObjectMapper.readValues() for bad JSON input

Tags: json, serialization, jackson, deserialization, jsonserializer

I work on an application that uses Jackson a lot. To understand how `readValue()` works for some corner cases, I set up a small experiment. First, a purposefully empty inner class:

```java
static class Empty {
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Empty class!";
    }
}
```

And now let's set some printouts:

```java
public void testFromJsonStringBadInput() {
    String[] emptyNullOrBadJsons = {"", "{}", "{", "}", "}{", "{{}", "{}}"};
    Class<?>[] types = {Empty.class, Object.class};
    for(String s: emptyNullOrBadJsons) {
        for(Class<?> clazz : types) {
            try {
                    System.out.println("new ObjectMapper().readValue(" + s +  ", " + clazz.getSimpleName() + ")=" + new ObjectMapper().readValue(s, clazz));
            } catch(Exception exc) {
                    System.out.println("Deserialization failure for Json string: " + s + " and class: " + clazz.getSimpleName() + ". Exception: " + exc.getClass().getSimpleName() +" and message: " + exc.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, for a bunch of edge-case JSONs, I deserialize into instances of `Empty` and `Object`, and print the objects produced by `readValue()`. Here's the output of this small code:

```
Deserialization failure for Json string:  and class: Empty. Exception: MismatchedInputException and message: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]
Deserialization failure for Json string:  and class: Object. Exception: MismatchedInputException and message: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]
new ObjectMapper().readValue({}, Empty)=Empty class!
new ObjectMapper().readValue({}, Object)={}
Deserialization failure for Json string: { and class: Empty. Exception: JsonEOFException and message: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 2]
Deserialization failure for Json string: { and class: Object. Exception: JsonEOFException and message: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 2]
Deserialization failure for Json string: } and class: Empty. Exception: JsonParseException and message: Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']' (for root starting at [Source: (String)"}"; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: (String)"}"; line: 1, column: 2]
Deserialization failure for Json string: } and class: Object. Exception: JsonParseException and message: Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']' (for root starting at [Source: (String)"}"; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: (String)"}"; line: 1, column: 2]
Deserialization failure for Json string: }{ and class: Empty. Exception: JsonParseException and message: Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']' (for root starting at [Source: (String)"}{"; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: (String)"}{"; line: 1, column: 2]
Deserialization failure for Json string: }{ and class: Object. Exception: JsonParseException and message: Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']' (for root starting at [Source: (String)"}{"; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: (String)"}{"; line: 1, column: 2]
Deserialization failure for Json string: {{} and class: Empty. Exception: JsonParseException and message: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{{}"; line: 1, column: 3]
Deserialization failure for Json string: {{} and class: Object. Exception: JsonParseException and message: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{{}"; line: 1, column: 3]
new ObjectMapper().readValue({}}, Empty)=Empty class!
new ObjectMapper().readValue({}}, Object)={}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I expected to see this output for all cases **except** for that last string, `"{}}"`. It seems that the Jackson deserializer parses this JSON just fine, without throwing exceptions, and this is something that succeeds for both my custom `Empty` class but also for `Object`. How come? I would have expected `readValue()` to throw here.

If it is in any way important, this is the only Jackson reference in my entire `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. Jackson chooses to not parse any part of the JSON following a successfully closed bracket pair. I added the following strings to the array of bad JSONs I was processing:

```
"{}}}", "{}}}}}}}}", "{ \"obj\":{}}}", "{\"name\" : \"Jason\"}}"
```

For the full method:

```java
public void testFromJsonStringBadInput() {
    String[] emptyNullOrBadJsons = {"", "{}", "{", "}", "}{", "{{}", "{}}", "{}}}", "{}}}}}}}}", "{ \"obj\":{}}}", "{\"name\" : \"Jason\"}}"};
    Class<?>[] types = {Empty.class, Object.class};
    for(String s: emptyNullOrBadJsons) {
        for(Class<?> clazz : types) {
            try {
                System.out.println("new ObjectMapper().readValue(" + s +  ", " + clazz.getSimpleName() + ")=" + new ObjectMapper().readValue(s, clazz));
            } catch(Exception exc) {
                System.out.println("Deserialization failure for Json string: " + s + " and class: " + clazz.getSimpleName() + ". Exception: " + exc.getClass().getSimpleName() +" and message: " + exc.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output supports the hypothesis, and the fact that `Empty` is not sufficient for parsing the strings `"{ \"obj\":{}}}"` and  `"{\"name\" : \"Jason\"}}"` is also reflected:

```
Deserialization failure for Json string:  and class: Empty. Exception: MismatchedInputException and message: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]
Deserialization failure for Json string:  and class: Object. Exception: MismatchedInputException and message: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]
new ObjectMapper().readValue({}, Empty)=Empty class!
new ObjectMapper().readValue({}, Object)={}
Deserialization failure for Json string: { and class: Empty. Exception: JsonEOFException and message: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 2]
Deserialization failure for Json string: { and class: Object. Exception: JsonEOFException and message: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 2]
Deserialization failure for Json string: } and class: Empty. Exception: JsonParseException and message: Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']' (for root starting at [Source: (String)"}"; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: (String)"}"; line: 1, column: 2]
Deserialization failure for Json string: } and class: Object. Exception: JsonParseException and message: Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']' (for root starting at [Source: (String)"}"; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: (String)"}"; line: 1, column: 2]
Deserialization failure for Json string: }{ and class: Empty. Exception: JsonParseException and message: Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']' (for root starting at [Source: (String)"}{"; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: (String)"}{"; line: 1, column: 2]
Deserialization failure for Json string: }{ and class: Object. Exception: JsonParseException and message: Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']' (for root starting at [Source: (String)"}{"; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: (String)"}{"; line: 1, column: 2]
Deserialization failure for Json string: {{} and class: Empty. Exception: JsonParseException and message: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{{}"; line: 1, column: 3]
Deserialization failure for Json string: {{} and class: Object. Exception: JsonParseException and message: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{{}"; line: 1, column: 3]
new ObjectMapper().readValue({}}, Empty)=Empty class!
new ObjectMapper().readValue({}}, Object)={}
new ObjectMapper().readValue({}}}, Empty)=Empty class!
new ObjectMapper().readValue({}}}, Object)={}
new ObjectMapper().readValue({}}}}}}}}, Empty)=Empty class!
new ObjectMapper().readValue({}}}}}}}}, Object)={}
Deserialization failure for Json string: { "obj":{}}} and class: Empty. Exception: UnrecognizedPropertyException and message: Unrecognized field "obj" (class com.drfirst.gear.user.context.util.AppUtilTest$Empty), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: (String)"{ "obj":{}}}"; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.drfirst.gear.user.context.util.AppUtilTest$Empty["obj"])
new ObjectMapper().readValue({ "obj":{}}}, Object)={obj={}}
Deserialization failure for Json string: {"name" : "Jason"}} and class: Empty. Exception: UnrecognizedPropertyException and message: Unrecognized field "name" (class com.drfirst.gear.user.context.util.AppUtilTest$Empty), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: (String)"{"name" : "Jason"}}"; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.drfirst.gear.user.context.util.AppUtilTest$Empty["name"])
new ObjectMapper().readValue({"name" : "Jason"}}, Object)={name=Jason}

Process finished with exit code 0
```